# How can I visualize 1D numeric data with R / tikz?

Tags: r, visualization

I have a text file with 166898 lines where each line has a single non-negative number. I would like to visualize it in the following way:

- The x-axis should range from `minimum_in_file` to `maximum_in_file`.
- The y-axis should range from `1` to `166898`
- The graph / bar plot should be increasing and visualize how many numbers are equal to the x-value or lower.

### Create data

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import random

minimum_in_file = 0
maximum_in_file = 378864471
numbers = []
for i in range(166898):
    numbers.append(random.randint(minimum_in_file, maximum_in_file))

numbers = sorted(numbers)

with open("times-sorted.txt", 'a') as f:
    for number in numbers:
        f.write(str(number) + "\n")
```

### Real data

When I execute `dput(head(mydata,20))` I get:

```
structure(list(X0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = "X0", row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

and

```
> dput(head(mydata,1000))
structure(list(X0 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 23L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 35L, 37L, 37L, 39L, 41L, 41L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
48L, 48L, 50L, 52L, 53L, 55L, 56L, 62L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 67L, 70L, 
79L, 79L, 80L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 88L, 88L, 89L, 91L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 
100L, 101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 103L, 104L, 104L, 107L, 109L, 109L, 
109L, 109L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 112L, 113L, 
113L, 114L, 114L, 114L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 
120L, 120L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 124L, 125L, 125L, 127L, 127L, 128L, 
128L, 128L, 129L, 129L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 
133L, 133L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 134L, 136L, 136L, 137L, 137L, 138L, 
139L, 140L, 141L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 143L, 143L, 144L, 144L, 144L, 
145L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 147L, 149L, 149L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 150L, 
150L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 151L, 152L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 154L, 
154L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 157L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 158L, 159L, 
160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 161L, 161L, 163L, 163L, 163L, 164L, 164L, 
164L, 164L, 164L, 165L, 165L, 166L, 166L, 167L, 167L, 167L, 167L, 
168L, 168L, 168L, 169L, 169L, 170L, 170L, 171L, 171L, 172L, 172L, 
172L, 172L, 173L, 173L, 173L, 174L, 174L, 175L, 175L, 175L, 176L, 
176L, 176L, 176L, 177L, 177L, 177L, 177L, 177L, 179L, 179L, 179L, 
180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 181L, 181L, 182L, 182L, 182L, 182L, 183L, 
183L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 185L, 185L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 187L, 
187L, 187L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 189L, 190L, 
190L, 190L, 190L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 191L, 
191L, 192L, 192L, 193L, 193L, 194L, 194L, 195L, 195L, 195L, 197L, 
197L, 197L, 197L, 197L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 198L, 199L, 
199L, 199L, 199L, 199L, 199L, 199L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 201L, 201L, 203L, 203L, 203L, 204L, 204L, 
204L, 205L, 205L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 206L, 207L, 
207L, 207L, 207L, 207L, 207L, 208L, 208L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 209L, 
209L, 209L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 210L, 211L, 211L, 212L, 213L, 
213L, 213L, 213L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 215L, 
215L)), .Names = "X0", row.names = c(NA, 1000L), class = "data.frame")
```

### What I've tried

I sorted the data with the unix tool `sort` and tried the following with `R version 3.0.1 (2013-05-16)`:

```
> mydata = read.csv("times-sorted.txt")
> accumulated_sum<-cumsum(mydata)
Warning message:
In lapply(X = x, FUN = .Generic, ...) :
  integer overflow in 'cumsum'; use 'cumsum(as.numeric(.))'
> plot(accumulated_sum)
```

But I don't understand how to fix the warning and the result is crappy:

[image]

How can I visualize it in a nice way?

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you make a nice reproducible example to go along with your question. You can have a look at [this SO thread on how to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: @EricFail: Thank you for the link. This is the first time I am using R, so the solution of my problems might be very simple. I've added a Python script that generates a similar dataset and I've added my `R` version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this source code here (https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/cum.c), and the statement
 `if(sum > INT_MAX || sum < 1 + INT_MIN)` where `INT_MAX` is `.Machine$integer.max` ,possibly this limit is being exceeded since you are applying `cumsum` to the entire dataset and not the variable of interest.

Since you have not posted your dataset structure, I think the row indices are being passed to `cumsum` and hence the warning,

```
N=166898
vec=1:N
#produces warning "Warning message: integer overflow in 'cumsum'; use 'cumsum(as.numeric(.))'"
cumsum(vec)
```

You need a cumulative frequency plot. Following is sample example adapted from 
    (http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/quantitative-data/cumulative-frequency-graph)

**Sample Example**

```
#For reproducibility
set.seed(100)
N=166898
vec=1:N

#Assuming min_val, max_val
min_val = 0
max_val = 378864471

min_break = 1e8
max_break = 4e8
seq_by = 1e8

#Create random values dataset
random_values = sample(min_val:max_val,N,replace = T)
DF=data.frame(vec,random_values)

#Compute Cumulative Frequency
#You can control the buckets by appropriate inputs to breaks
breaks = seq(min_break, max_break, by=seq_by)

#Creates buckets [x,y), [y,z) etc.
DF.cut = cut( DF$random_values, breaks, right=FALSE) 

#Computes count of observations in various buckets and cumulative frequency
DF.freq=table(DF.cut)
DF.cumfreq = c(0, cumsum(DF.freq))

#Plot Data
plot(breaks, DF.cumfreq,main="Cumulative Frequency of XYZ",xlab="Range of Values",ylab="# of Observations < X")
lines(breaks, DF.cumfreq)
```

[image]

**Your data**

I have plotted the below plot using the data sample you provided, but the following should work for your file(s) now.

```
#Replace the appropriate filename here
mydata = read.table("times-sorted.txt")

min_val_new = min(mydata)
max_val_new = max(mydata)


breaks_new = seq(from=min_val_new,to=max_val_new,length.out=5)

#Creates buckets [x,y), [y,z) etc.
DF.cut_new = cut(mydata[,1], breaks_new, right=FALSE) 

#Computes count of observations in various buckets and cumulative frequency
DF.freq_new=table(DF.cut_new)
DF.cumfreq_new = c(0, cumsum(DF.freq_new))

#Plot Data
plot(breaks_new, DF.cumfreq_new,main="Cumulative Frequency of ABC",xlab="Range of Values",ylab="# of Observations < X")
lines(breaks_new, DF.cumfreq_new)
```

[image]

**Exponential Plot**

Define your breakpoints cutoff1=10000 and cutoff2=60000 and include them in 'breaks' calculation and plotting using `ggplot2` with log axis

```
set.seed(100)
require(ggplot2)

N=166898
vec=1:N

#Assuming min_val, max_val
min_val = 0
max_val = 378864471

min_break=0
max_break=4e8


#Create random values dataset
random_values = sample(min_val:max_val,N,replace = T)
DF=data.frame(vec,random_values)

#Define your data breakpoints

cutoff1=10000
cutoff2=60000

#Compute Cumulative Frequency
#You can control the buckets by appropriate inputs to breaks
breaks = c(min_break,cutoff1,seq(cutoff2, max_break, length.out=30))

#Creates buckets [x,y), [y,z) etc.
DF.cut = cut( DF$random_values, breaks, right=FALSE) 

#Computes count of observations in various buckets and cumulative frequency
DF.freq=table(DF.cut)
DF.cumfreq = c(0, cumsum(DF.freq))

#Plot Data
#plot(breaks, DF.cumfreq,main="Cumulative Frequency of XYZ",xlab="Range of Values",ylab="# of Observations < X")
#lines(breaks, DF.cumfreq)

gg.df=data.frame(breaks,DF.cumfreq)

ggplot(gg.df, aes(x = breaks,y=DF.cumfreq)) +  geom_line() + scale_x_log10() + 
xlab("Range of Values: Log Axis") +
ylab("# of Observations < X") +
ggtitle("Cumulative Frequency of Variable")
```

[image]

Comment: could you please add the output of `dput(head(mydata,20))`, I can then modify to reflect your inputs

Comment: It works! Thank you very much (+1)! Do you think it is possible to make the x-axis grow exponentially? (Most of my data is below 10 000, but some is over 60 000)

Comment: I have included your breakpoints, 10000 and 60000 in the above exponential plot, is this sufficient for you